# Nodemailer with Gmail on Loopback error - Object #<Object> has no method 'getToken'

Tags: node.js, gmail, nodemailer, loopback

I am learning Loopback and I decided to make some email sending. I want to use gmail account.
I created remote method and configured datasources. Here is how it looks:

```
"myEmailDataSource": {
"name": "myEmailDataSource",
"connector": "mail",
"transports": [
  {
    "type": "smtp",
    "host": "smtp.gmail.com",
    "auth": {
      "xoauth2": {
        "user": "myMail@gmail.com",
        "clientId": "myClientId.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "clientSecret": "mySecret",
        "refreshToken": "myToken"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

}

But when I want to send an email, it throws this error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getToken'
at SMTPConnection._handleXOauth2Token (/home/arth95/Projects/firstCMS/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/nodemailer/node_modules/nodemailer-smtp-transport/node_modules/smtp-connection/src/smtp-connection.js:961:67)
at SMTPConnection.login (/home/arth95/Projects/firstCMS/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/nodemailer/node_modules/nodemailer-smtp-transport/node_modules/smtp-connection/src/smtp-connection.js:233:18)
at SMTPTransport.<anonymous> (/home/arth95/Projects/firstCMS/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/nodemailer/node_modules/nodemailer-smtp-transport/src/smtp-transport.js:96:24)
at SMTPConnection.g (events.js:180:16)
at SMTPConnection.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at SMTPConnection._actionEHLO (/home/arth95/Projects/firstCMS/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/nodemailer/node_modules/nodemailer-smtp-transport/node_modules/smtp-connection/src/smtp-connection.js:692:10)
at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/home/arth95/Projects/firstCMS/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/nodemailer/node_modules/nodemailer-smtp-transport/node_modules/smtp-connection/src/smtp-connection.js:511:16)
at SMTPConnection._onData (/home/arth95/Projects/firstCMS/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/nodemailer/node_modules/nodemailer-smtp-transport/node_modules/smtp-connection/src/smtp-connection.js:357:10)
at CleartextStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at CleartextStream.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

I had exact same problem. Did you find any solution for this?
As a workaround I've done following.

1. create a boot script in server\boot
2. in the script wrote following code

> var email = app.models.Email;
>
> var auth = email.dataSource.connector.transports[0].transporter.options.auth;
>
> auth.xoauth2 = require('xoauth2').createXOAuth2Generator(auth.xoauth2);

This converts the xoauth2 object that you defined in data source to XOAuth2Generator object that is needed by nodemailer.

You need to have [xoauth2](https://github.com/andris9/xoauth2) module installed.

There should be a better way to handle this. But so far I've not found it, so using this workaround.